# AWS S3 Allows reading of all objects except a specific folder

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, aws-policies

1. How can I allow reading of all objects except a single folder and its contents?
   The rule below blocks me the whole bucket.. (can't read the bucket)
2. If this feature isn't possible, how can I allow reading on files at the root but deny on all subfolders?

```
{
    "Version": "2012-10-17",
    "Statement": [
        {
            "Sid": "ListBucket",
            "Effect": "Allow",
            "Action": "s3:ListBucket",
            "Resource": "arn:aws:s3:::my-bucket"
        },
        {
            "Sid": "ReadOnly",
            "Effect": "Allow",
            "Action": "s3:GetObject",
            "Resource": "arn:aws:s3:::my-bucket/*"
        },
        {
            "Sid": "DenyOneFolder",
            "Effect": "Deny",
            "Action": "s3:GetObject",
            "Resource": [
                "arn:aws:s3:::my-bucket/my-folder",
                "arn:aws:s3:::my-bucket/my-folder/*"
            ]
        }
    ]
}
```

My bucket strcture:

- my-bucket

  - my-folder

    - object3
  - object1
  - object2

Comment: This is an IAM policy that denies GetObject on `arn:aws:s3:::my-bucket/my-folder/*`. You don't need `arn:aws:s3:::my-bucket/my-folder`, but that shouldn't cause a problem (I'd remove it anyway). Are you 100% sure that you are able to get objects below `s3://my-bucket/my-folder/` with credentials based on this IAM policy?

Comment: Yes, same behavior without `arn:aws:s3:::my-bucket/my-folder`.. however, without the `Deny` rule i have access to the whole bucket. So, yes, I'm confirming that I have a problem with the `Deny` rule. :(

Comment: How are you testing this? If you use the aws console to download object that's not valid, you must access the url directly.

Comment: @RaduDiță why is that not valid? Assuming that the user logged in with IAM User credentials associated with this policy.

Comment: OK, I'm assuming the mistake here is that you are conflating 'listing' with 'getting'. You can't prevent this IAM user listing a subset of the objects in the bucket. But this policy will prevent the IAM user 'getting' the objects under s3://my-bucket/my-folder/ where 'getting' means downloading.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can add an explicit `Deny` in your bucket policy for Listing objects that matches the prefix `my-folder`.

**Edit**: This policy will work only if the list bucket request contains the prefix.

```
{
    "Version": "2012-10-17",
    "Statement": [
        {
            "Sid": "ListBucket",
            "Effect": "Allow",
            "Action": "s3:ListBucket",
            "Resource": "arn:aws:s3:::my-bucket"
        },
        {
            "Sid": "ReadOnly",
            "Effect": "Allow",
            "Action": "s3:GetObject",
            "Resource": "arn:aws:s3:::my-bucket/*"
        },
        {
            "Sid": "DenyOneFolderRead",
            "Effect": "Deny",
            "Action": "s3:GetObject",
            "Resource": [
                "arn:aws:s3:::my-bucket/my-folder/*"
            ]
        },
        {
            "Sid": "DenyOneFolderList",
            "Effect": "Deny",
            "Action": "s3:ListBucket",
            "Resource": "arn:aws:s3:::my-bucket",
            "Condition" : {
                "StringEquals" : {
                    "s3:prefix": "my-folder" 
                }
            } 
        }
    ]
}
```

Comment: How will this prevent the IAM user simply listing the entire bucket (by providing *no* prefix to the ListBuckets call)?

Comment: Did you test this? Specifically, listing the bucket (not bucket+prefix). It will only prevent this: `aws s3 ls my-bucket/my-folder/`. It will not prevent this: `aws s3 ls my-bucket --recursive`.

Comment: Ah, I missed that!

Answer (score 0):

The policy works correctly, though I would remove the Deny on `arn:aws:s3:::my-bucket/my-folder` because it's not useful.

I think the confusion here is that you are expecting this policy to prevent the IAM user listing and/or getting the objects under `s3://my-bucket/my-folder/`. It won't do that, specifically the listing part, and in fact you cannot do that. You can't control a user's ability to list the bucket at a granular level (e.g. below a specific prefix).

The policy will successfully prevent the user getting (as in downloading) objects under `s3://my-bucket/my-folder/`.